# Link programs running on 2 Raspberry Pi's

Tags: python

I'm looking to have 2 separate Raspberry Pi's running complimentary programs. One drives a display, the other rocking a PiFace. (since the display uses GPIO, I can't use one Pi)

I'd like a button press on the PiFace to trigger an action (displaying something) on the other raspberry pi. Obviously, this can't occur over GPIO, but ethernet and USB are both game.

Any help would be appreciated, many thanks!

Note: programs are written in Python.

Comment: I think ZeroMQ would be great for this. It lets you pass messages between processes, threads, and computers over a number of protocols. It has bindings for all sorts of languages including python.

Answer (score 1):

If the Pi are networked you can use my [pigpio](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/index.html) for this purpose.

You can control the GPIO on a Pi from a [Python script](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html) running on the local Pi or a remote Pi (or both).

In fact the controlling Python script does not need to be running on a Pi at all, it may run on a Windows, Mac, or Linux box as long as it has a network connections to the Pis.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import pigpio

# other initialisation code

pi_local = pigpio.pi()      # pi_local accesses the local Pi's GPIO
pi_tom = pigpio.pi('tom')   # pi_tom accesses tom's GPIO
pi_dick = pigpio.pi('dick') # pi_dick accesses dick's GPIO

pi_local.write(4, 0)    # set local Pi's GPIO 4 low
pi_tom.write(4, 1)      # set tom's GPIO 4 to high
level = pi_dick.read(4) # get level of dick's GPIO 4

# when (and if) the script finishes disconnect

pi_local.stop() # disconnect from local Pi
pi_tom.stop()   # disconnect from tom
pi_dick.stop()  # disconnect from dick
```

The pigpio daemon needs to be running on each Pi to be controlled.  It may be started at boot with the one-off command `sudo systemctl enable pigpiod`.